# Linear Transformation - linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, transformation

$T:\mathbb{R}_2[x] \mapsto \mathbb{R}_2[x]$ s.t.:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
T(1) = 3+2x+4x^2, \\
T(x) = 2+2x^2, \\
T(x^2) = 4+2x+3x^2.
\end{array}
$$

Is there base $B$ of $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ that 
$[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\-1 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: Still need help to understnad. I'm sorry if I nag